# How to throw 404 error in drupal 7 programmatically without render 2 times?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to throw 404 error in Drupal 7 programmatically without render 2 times?
The 404 page shows two times while calling Drupal code below

```
return drupal_not_found();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `drupal_not_found()` is meant to be called outside the context of the drupal page delivery system (cf. [`menu_execute_active_handler()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/7.x)).

So if you are in a page callback, just

```
return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
```